# ClosedXML AddConditionalFormat() adds quotes to value in Excel (French)

Tags: c#, excel, localization, closedxml

So I am trying to use ClosedXML.  I have been using it successfully until I come across localization.  The conditional formatting works on English, Italian, and German versions of Windows.  It does not in French.

The `AddConditionalFormat().WhenEqualOrLessThan()` methods do not work correctly when the locale is French.  It adds quotes to the conditional statement.  When I open it in Excel I get the Rule:

`Cell Value <= "-98.00002"`

It is supposed to be:

`Cell Value <= -98.00002`

I run this with the other languages and it works without a problem.

```
ws.Range(r, 1, r, 2).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.General;  // G3 compatibility

ws.Cell(r, 2).AddConditionalFormat().WhenEqualOrLessThan(-98.00002f)
    .Font.SetFontColor(XLColor.LightGray);
ws.SheetView.FreezeRows(2);
ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the **f** off the tail end of `-98.00002`? It would seem that the *f* is forcing the value to be treated as a string.

Comment: I removed the `f` from the float number and this did not fix the problem.  The Conditional Formatting still added the quotes.  Again only in the French version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Jeeped, I started looking deep into the code.  I found that the value was being changed at the time of the save to the string in question.

`GetQuoted` in `XLCFCellIsConverter.cs` had trouble parsing the Double (-98.00002) that I use.  When my machine was in the French Culture it was not able to parse.  So I modified the call from:

```
    private String GetQuoted(XLFormula formula)
    {
        String value = formula.Value;
        Double num;
        if ((!Double.TryParse(value, out num) && !formula.IsFormula) && value[0] != '\"' && !value.EndsWith("\""))
            return String.Format("\"{0}\"", value.Replace("\"", "\"\""));

        return value;
    }
```

To:

```
    private String GetQuoted(XLFormula formula)
    {
        String value = formula.Value;
        Double num;
            if ((!Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out num) && !formula.IsFormula) && value[0] != '\"' && !value.EndsWith("\""))
                return String.Format("\"{0}\"", value.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
        return value;
    }
```